# Apple Mach-O Linker Error When Building App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
duplicate symbol _y in:
/Users/archanamehta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuideforCODGhosts-ftrljupdxywopwckemagyiliitss/Build/Intermediates/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecondaryWeaponsViewController.o
/Users/archanamehta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuideforCODGhosts-ftrljupdxywopwckemagyiliitss/Build/Intermediates/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Objects-normal/i386/PrimaryWeaponsViewController.o
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have an error in my application. Above is the error I am getting. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

Thanks

EDIT
Source code for .h file of PrimaryWeaponsViewController
http://gyazo.com/1dd400959f043bddbc59ec8d0c4f6c60

Source code for .h file SecondaryWeaponsViewController
http://gyazo.com/76b3d1fa2b766e904af41489e36cba60

Comment: Don't use global variables. But if you do, at least make them `static`. No, really, don't use them.

Comment: I have added code from my .h files for both ViewControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lines provided have the name of the files where the error is:

`SecondaryWeaponsViewController`
`PrimaryWeaponsViewController`

Look at these files.

Best bet given no source code is that there is a variable _y that is declared a global. Note that `@propertie`s *auto-generate instance variables and add a leading "_"* to them.

Post the code for these methods, how they are related and the portions dealing with an variable "y"/ This could be a variable declared in a .h header file that both classes import.